# Access To Recursive Tree With Cte

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 table of data: some people has access a branch(s) and branch can have some sub branches

### Table Persons

```
ID     PName
1       P1
2       P2
```

### Table Branches

```
ID    Title    BrachIDRef
0      Master    null
1        B1       0 
2        B2       1
3        B3       2
4        B4       2
5        B5       1
6        B6       0
7        B7       6
```

### Table PersonBranches

```
Id  PersonIDref     BranchIDref
1   1                   1
2   2                   6
3   2                   2
```

And Result I need is Access of Persons to branches and Sub branches in SQL Server Query like this :

```
P1  B1 
P1  (and All Childs of B1 - for each child have a record of data)
P2  B6
P2  and All Childs if B6
P2  B2
P2  and All Childs Of B2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? What is the *actual* expected results you're after here, as I *assume* you aren't actually after a row with the value `'(and All Childs of B1 - for each child have a record of data)'` for the second column. Are you looking for multiple rows, a delimited list, something else..?

Comment: How did P2 and B6 got together?

Comment: at Table PersonBranches row 2 P2 was access to BranchIDRef 6 and BranchID 6 is B6

Comment: Ofc i means multiple record and for short answer i write like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use recursive CTE for Branches table and you need to use ROW_NUMBER() for generate dynamic unique record ID, which will use order records.

Before UNION ALL select query generate parent record values with record ID.
After UNION ALL select query generate child records based on parent record.

Please check below query for your expected result.

```
SELECT * INTO #Persons
FROM (
SELECT '1' ID,'P1' PName UNION ALL
SELECT '2','P2') a

SELECT * INTO #Branches
FROM (        
SELECT '0' ID,'Master' Title,NULL BrachIDRef UNION ALL
SELECT '1','B1','0' UNION ALL  
SELECT '2','B2','1' UNION ALL
SELECT '3','B3','2' UNION ALL
SELECT '4','B4','2' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','B5','1' UNION ALL
SELECT '6','B6','0' UNION ALL
SELECT '7','B7','6'
) a

SELECT * INTO #PersonBranches
FROM (       
SELECT '1' Id,'1' PersonIDref,'1' BranchIDref UNION ALL
SELECT '2' Id,'2' PersonIDref,'6' BranchIDref UNION ALL
SELECT '3' Id,'2' PersonIDref,'2' BranchIDref
) a

;WITH branchCTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        B.ID,B.Title,B.BrachIDRef,P.PName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.BrachIDRef,B.ID) AS RID
    FROM #Branches B
    INNER JOIN #PersonBranches PB ON PB.BranchIDref = B.ID
    INNER JOIN #Persons P ON P.ID = PB.PersonIDref
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        B1.ID,B1.Title,B1.BrachIDRef,C.PName,C.RID
    FROM #Branches B1
    INNER JOIN branchCTE C ON C.ID = B1.BrachIDRef
    WHERE B1.BrachIDRef > 0
)
SELECT
    C.PName,
    C.Title
FROM branchCTE C
ORDER BY C.RID

DROP TABLE #Persons;
DROP TABLE #Branches;
DROP TABLE #PersonBranches;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use connect by prior with different CTE and union it with your normal query to fetch all the children as follows:

```
cte as
(SELECT ANCESTOR,  
    LISTAGG(case when Title = ANCESTOR then null else title end, '/') within group (order by null) as pth from
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID,
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT Title as ANCESTOR, 
        Title
     FROM Branches
     CONNECT BY PRIOR ID =  BrachIDRef)
     GROUP BY
     ANCESTOR)
--
SELECT pb.id, p.pname, b.title
    from PersonBranches pb
        join persons p on (p.id = pb.PersonIDref) 
        join Branches b on (pb.BranchIDref = b.id)
union all
SELECT pb.id, p.pname, c.pth
    from PersonBranches pb
        join persons p on (p.id = pb.PersonIDref)   
        join Branches b on (pb.BranchIDref = b.id)
        join cte c on (b.title = c.ANCESTOR)
order by id;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1837f0f929ea4babbee58d7b56b7348d)

Cheers!!

Comment: `LIST_AGG` isn't a T-SQL function

Comment: Ok, I have given answer for oracle. You can just take an idea from it